# What is a good charset for distinguishable base256 visualizations?

Tags: unicode

Suppose I want to display a sequence of base256 digits using only one unicode character per digit, in a way that maximizes distinguishability and simplicity. What is a good set of 256 characters to accomplish this goal?

I suppose something with easy geometric shapes such as lines, circles, squares would be very nice; has this been done?

Edit: for example, this seems like a good start,

```
≻ ∧ ≺ ∨ ⊐ ⊓ ⊏ ⊔
⊣ ⊤ ⊢ ⊥ ∩ ∪ ∆ ∇
◊ ○ ◠ ◡ ⊟ ⊞ ⊖ ⊕
```

There are only simple shapes which are easy to distinguish, but still a long way to do til 256.

Comment: With a lookup table you can choose any characters you want to represent the base-256 symbols for 0-255.  Choose whatever "maximizes distinguishability and simplicity" for you :^)  Here are the  http://www.unicode.org/charts/.

Comment: @MarkTolonen ... I'm precisely asking if someone has done that. It won't be an easy task to figure out a list of 256 distinguishable characters... even more so a list of quality (i.e., maximizing simplicity). It'd be awesome to have something with some research / background.

Comment: OK, it will be interesting if you get an answer.  Most people would use a two-character code per digit and call it hexadecimal :^)

Comment: Yep, I just wanted to halve the size of the visualization :) also, our alphabet isn't exactly optimized for distinguishability (for example, I and l look identical, many characters are just other characters scaled up like o O, x X...).

Comment: May I ask if you found some more chars? I am searching for the exact same thing. I am trying to visualize a mapping of different states. A combination of colors and distinguishable chars is how I want to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

The closest answer would be, IMHO, [Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

[image]

For showing above with clickable info, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Answer (score 0):

[Emojis in Base256](https://github.com/Equim-chan/base256) *store four bytes per character*.

So an encoded sequence of bytes would become 4 times bigger! Because each byte value (0-255) represents an emoji that needs four bytes.

Visually it looks compressed and is easier to copy/paste.